# What does Vise Grip do if you use two of the same dice?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

The description for Vise Grip takes says it returns two of the difference between dice. What happens if you use two dice with the same value so there's no difference between the dice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens if you use Vice Grip with 2 dice of the same value. The dice get used up and and you get nothing in return.

Honestly I don't know what I expected.